# Woocommerce: How to round prices to 2 decimals on checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am aware that Woocommerce is calculating prices in 4 decimals, which is creating me problem later in my accounting software when order is transferred. I am getting 0,01 difference when multiple pieces are ordered.

Prices in Woocommerce are displayed in 2 decimals, but on cart and checkout i need also to be in calculation rounded in 2 decimals so i dont get 0,01 difference when transferred in accounting software.

I would really like to get your help on writting functions.php code for this..
No php code expert, so i am not able to write this.

Comment: You should not use decimals for calculation at all. Just divide by 100 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Prices in Woocommerce are displayed in 2 decimals, but on cart and checkout i need also to be in calculation rounded in 2 decimals so i dont get 0,01 difference when transferred in accounting software.

I'm not sure how your accounting software works, but if your goal is to round the total to 2 decimal points, this might help.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_cart_decimal_calculated_total' );

function custom_cart_decimal_calculated_total( $total ) {
    $rounded_total = number_format( round( $total, 1 ), 2 );
    return $rounded_total;
}
```

Also, in case you're not aware, you can get rid of the 0.01 difference by changing the "Number of decimal" value to 1 in WooCommerce -> General -> Settings, however, this will apply to the entire store, not just the total.